# ruby fibonacci.rb from launchscool's website? I cannot not understand it

Tags: ruby

```
# fibonacci.rb

def fibonacci(number)
  if number < 2
    number
  else
    fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2)
  end
end

puts fibonacci(6)
```

result is 8 but when I do it in my head I get 9.

Link to site https://launchschool.com/books/ruby/read/loops_iterators 
code is located near the bottom. I am just not getting it.

Comment: Fibonacci: 1,1,2,3,5,**8**,13 ... How did you get `9`?

Comment: Can you show what steps you followed in your head before reaching to answer `9`?

Answer (score 3):

Let's do the math:

```
fibonacci(6) = fibonacci(5) + fibonacci(4) # else part
fibonacci(5) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3) # else part
fibonacci(4) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2) # else part
fibonacci(3) = fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1) # else part
fibonacci(2) = fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0) # else part
fibonacci(1) = 1                           # if part
fibonacci(0) = 0                           # if part
```

We can now solve this bottom up. First, we can calculate `fibonacci(2)` by inserting the values for `fibonacci(1)` and `fibonacci(0)`:

```
fibonacci(6) = fibonacci(5) + fibonacci(4)
fibonacci(5) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)
fibonacci(4) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2)
fibonacci(3) = fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)
fibonacci(2) = 1 + 0 #=> 1
fibonacci(1) = 1
fibonacci(0) = 0
```

Then, we calculate `fibonacci(3)` by inserting the values for `fibonacci(2)` and `fibonacci(1)`:

```
fibonacci(6) = fibonacci(5) + fibonacci(4)
fibonacci(5) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)
fibonacci(4) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2)
fibonacci(3) = 1 + 1 #=> 2
fibonacci(2) = 1 + 0 #=> 1
fibonacci(1) = 1
fibonacci(0) = 0
```

Next, `fibonacci(4)` by inserting the values for `fibonacci(3)` and `fibonacci(2)`:

```
fibonacci(6) = fibonacci(5) + fibonacci(4)
fibonacci(5) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)
fibonacci(4) = 2 + 1 #=> 3
fibonacci(3) = 1 + 1 #=> 2
fibonacci(2) = 1 + 0 #=> 1
fibonacci(1) = 1     #=> 1
fibonacci(0) = 0     #=> 0
```

After that `fibonacci(5)`:

```
fibonacci(6) = fibonacci(5) + fibonacci(4)
fibonacci(5) = 3 + 2 #=> 5
fibonacci(4) = 2 + 1 #=> 3
fibonacci(3) = 1 + 1 #=> 2
fibonacci(2) = 1 + 0 #=> 1
fibonacci(1) = 1     #=> 1
fibonacci(0) = 0     #=> 0
```

And finally `fibonacci(6)`:

```
fibonacci(6) = 5 + 3 #=> 8
fibonacci(5) = 3 + 2 #=> 5
fibonacci(4) = 2 + 1 #=> 3
fibonacci(3) = 1 + 1 #=> 2
fibonacci(2) = 1 + 0 #=> 1
fibonacci(1) = 1     #=> 1
fibonacci(0) = 0     #=> 0
```

Comment: I understand the countdown from the first code block, I just dont get the 5 + 3, I have struggled through life with understanding . Sorry if I cannot grasp this

Comment: @Stefan great explanation, especially with the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

Their code simply follows the definition of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) for n >= 2
```

The line

```
if number < 2
    number
```

combines the first two conditions, while the rest is for n >= 2. Can you maybe give us how you worked it out to 9, and we can help you understand where you went wrong?

M

Comment: I just added the 5 + 4 to get 9, I see that now you keep adding the values until you get to 0 and 1 but I still dont get how it gets to 5 + 3, I'm new to coding and learning as been a bit tough, I am trying , sorry

Comment: No need to apologise, it's fine to struggle. Everybody did at some point. I think I can see where your misunderstanding is coming from. When you see fibonacci(6), you look at line 5, and you add (6 - 1) to (6 - 2), am I correct? If that's the case, it's a minor misunderstanding. You must first call the fibonacco function on (6 - 1) and on (6 - 2), then add the result of those. Check @Stefan for a great explanation. Maybe try it for fibonacci(3) before you try fibonacci(6)